# Ricci flow preserves locally symmetry along the flow

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow, flows, kahler-ricci-flow

Let $(M,g_0)$ be a closed locally symmetric Riemannian manifold and let $g(t)_{t\in[0,T)}$ be a solution to the Ricci flow on $M$ with $g(0)=g_0$. How one can prove that Ricci flow preserves locally symmetry of $(M,g_0)$ along the flow. In the other words, how one can prove that $(M,g(t))_{t\in[0,T)}$ is locally symmetric along the flow too?

Comment: The covariant derivative of the curvature tensor satisfies a homogeneous nonlinear heat equation. Since it vanishes at the start, by the uniqueness of the solution to the initial value problem, it vanishes for positive time.