# Ricci flow on locally symmetric noncompact manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-equations, counterexamples, ricci-flow, uniqueness-theorems

As it is mentioned by Deane Yang in [Ricci flow preserves locally symmetry along the flow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325676/ricci-flow-preserves-locally-symmetry-along-the-flow), we know the local symmetry is preserved under the Ricci flow on the compact manifold since we have the evolution equation $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\nabla \text{Rm})=\Delta(\nabla \text{Rm})+\text{Rm} \ast \nabla \text{Rm}$$
and the uniqueness of the solution due to the compactness of the manifold.

My question is : Can we generalize this argument to the noncompact case?

Even though we have a same evolution equation, as it is mentioned in https://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.3081.pdf, we know that the uniqueness is not automatically given when the manifold is noncompact and there is no growth condition (for example, there is a famous example of Tychonoff : $$u(x,t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}\frac{d^k}{dt^k}e^{-\frac{1}{t^2}}$$ satisfying $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u=\Delta u$ but $u(x,0)\equiv0$). If it can't be generalized, is there any well known counterexample for this case (that is, $(M,g(0))$ is locally symmetric but $(M,g(t))$ is not for any $t>0$)?

Comment: Ricci flow is unique in the class of complete metrics of bounded curvature, by a result of Chen and Zhu, https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1175266184. Any locally symmetric metric has bounded curvature.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek Thank you for your answer! It was a trivial question...